# Inner join on a distinct set of parameters

Tags: mysql, sql

I've tried a few of the similar SO questions, but I can't seem to figure it out.

On the first inner join, I only want to bring in DISTINCT `function` columns code and serial_id. So when I do my SUM selects, it calculates one per distinct. Ie there are multiple rows with the same func.code and func.serial_id. I only want 1 of them.

```
SELECT
    sl.imp_id,
    lat.version,
    SUM(IF(lat.status = 'P',1,0)) AS powered,
    SUM(IF(lat.status = 'F',1,0)) AS functional
FROM slots sl
INNER JOIN functions func ON sl.id = func.slot_id
INNER JOIN latest_status lat ON lat.code = func.code
                             AND lat.serial_id = func.serial_id
WHERE sl.id=55
GROUP BY sl.imp_id, lat.version
```

EDIT 2 - sample data explanation -------------------

```
slots - id, imp_id, name
functions - id, slot_id, code, serial_id
latest_status - id, code, serial_id, version, status

    **slots**

    id  imp_id      name
    1    5       'the name'
    2    5       'another name'
    3    5       'name!'
    4    5       'name!!'
    5    5       'name!!!'
    6    5       'testing'
    7    5       'hi'
    8    5       'test'


    **functions**

    id   slot_id     code     serial_id
    1       1       11HRK        10
    2       2       22RMJ        11
    3       3       26OLL        01
    4       4       22RMJ        00
    6       6       11HRK        10
    7       7       11HRK        10
    8       8       22RMJ        00

    **latest_status**

   id     code     serial_id    version    status
    1     11HRK       10         1           F
    1     11HRK       10         2           P
    3     22RMJ       11         1           P
    4     22RMJ       11         2           F
    5     26OLL       01         1           F
    6     26OLL       01         2           P
    7     22RMJ       00         1           F
    8     22RMJ       00         2           F
```

After running the query, the result should look like this:

```
imp_id    version    powered    functional
   5         1          1           3
   5         2          2           2
```

The function table gets rolled up based on the code, serial_id. 1 row per code, serial_id.
It then gets joined onto the latest_status table based on the serial_id and code, which is a one (functions) to many (latest_status) relationship, so two rows come out of this, one for each version.

Comment: Do you have many `lat.version` for same `lat.code` & `lat.serial_id`?

Comment: Yes, there are two versions for each code/serial_id

Comment: So at least because you are grouping by `lat.version` you will have `func.code/func.serial_id` repeated 2 times. Then for a given `sl.id` you have many `imp_id`?

Comment: imp_id is a FK. imps have many slots

Comment: Don't you need to see the `sl.imp_id` and `lat.version` columns in the output if you're grouping by them?  Otherwise, you just have a set of sum values and no identification of what they refer to.

Comment: Yes, I was trying to make the query easy to read, but it seems to have created another problem.. =/

Comment: Do to others and myself missing what it LOOKs like you want... can you provide some SAMPLE data from the respective tables and the final of what you want it TO look like when done.  Thus the data should show what is apparently showing multiple where you want the DISTINCT count basis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about using `DISTINCT`?

```
SELECT
    SUM(IF(lat.status = 'P',1,0)) AS powered,
    SUM(IF(lat.status = 'F',1,0)) AS functional
FROM slots sl
INNER JOIN (Select DISTINCT id1, code, serial_id from functions) f On sl.rid = f.id1
INNER JOIN latest_status lat ON lat.code = f.code
                             AND lat.serial_id = f.serial_id
WHERE sl.id=55
GROUP BY sl.imp_id, lat.version
```

Comment: I need the distinct of serial_id/code.. if I run the distinct in the select statement, it will run it on the unique id1 using for joining, and won't eliminate anything =/

Comment: The nested select got me on my way to an answer, though it isn't comprehensive.. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you want only the distinct code and serial_id, you need to group by those not the imp_id and version. And end up with something like

```
SELECT
    SUM(IF(lat.status = 'P',1,0)) AS powered,
    SUM(IF(lat.status = 'F',1,0)) AS functional
FROM slots sl
INNER JOIN functions func ON sl.rid = func.id1
INNER JOIN latest_status lat ON lat.code = func.code
                             AND lat.serial_id = func.serial_id
WHERE sl.id=55
GROUP BY func.code, func.serial_id
```

However, this could all be rubish, without more data as tgo what some of those other columns are, but they dont seem to be the ones you wanted to group by.

Comment: The problem is that func is a subset of a slot, so when I group by func.code, func.serial id, it doesn't group the information within the func subsets